# How to concatenate short and char array using strcat in C

Tags: c, strcat

I have a short type variable `X` which I wanna concatenate with `char[]` type of variable `Y`. I tried `itoa` function but I guess that function is not available to me.So is there any other simple option like `strcat(Y,X)`?

**[Additional Info]**
I know I can use `sprintf()` but I need to pass the final output to some Oracle in-built function and I don't know if sprintf() can give me string or char[] as an output.

Comment: If X is a short, you can use a union to pull out the two chars.

Comment: @Jim: A short is not necessarily 2 bytes long.

Comment: char[] is a string, or do you mean string as an oracle built-in type. Anyway, the result obtained from sprintf is char[]

Comment: Name a common system where it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sprintf:

```
sprintf(Z, "%s%d", Y, X);
```

Comment: or without `Z`: `sprintf(Y+strlen(Y), "%d", X);`